# recursion not stopping with 'if'

Tags: string, python-2.7, loops, recursion

I am trying to write a code which prints True if given string has at max 2 consecutive c, and at max 1 b. I am using recursion to reduce the string and check that at max 'c' is present in the same index twice.But my recursion is not stopping till it empties the whole list. Can you please suggest what's wrong with my code. Thanks!

```
def stringcond(N,count=0,k=0):
    N=list(N)
    if(N.count('b')>1):
        return False
    if len(N)<2:
        return True
    else:
        for i,j in enumerate(N):
            if(j=='c'):
                del N[i]
                count+=1
            if(k==i and count>2):
                return False
            stringcond(N,count=count,k=i)
    return True
```

Comment: don't change a sequence while you are iterating over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several mistakes.  First, why are you splitting the characters into a list?  There is a perfectly good **count** method for strings.

Your recursion fails because you ignore the return value.  You would want something like

```
if not stringcond(N,count=count,k=i):
    return False
# I make no claim that this logic is correct.
```

In any case, there is no need to recur.  Use **count** to check the quantity of "b" and many-'c' substrings:

```
def stringcond(s, c_max=0):
    return s.count('b') <= 1 and \
           s.count("c" * (c_max+1)) == 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe I should use count for strings. I am using recursion as i have to find presence of more than 2  consecutive 'c' character.  Count would just have provided me with count irrespective of it's location.

Comment: This does not require recursion.  Look at my solution: you need only to ensure that there are not 3 consecutive 'c's in the string.

Comment: Oh, right!. but it's too literal. I was thinking in terms of reusability as in what if question extends to 50 consecutive c in a large string.

Comment: Done; you can now enter a maximum number of 'c' characters.  This still doesn't warrant recursion.  :-)

Comment: Lols. Thanks!. and I wrote 10 lines of code for that :) !!

Comment: Welcome to Python (and other 4th-generation languages).  If you can describe a manipulation in simple terms of your variables, there's probably a language facility to do it.

Comment: Please remember to accept your favourite answer, so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: Thanks. Just closed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the result of the stringcond call. Now your function will only return whatever was determined on the top level call.